# WP Better Emails Plugin - own tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create my own tag in the plugin WP Better Email. I would like to have a dynamic title (%title%)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails

I use the wp_mail function.

```
$header = "test";

wp_mail( $mail, $subject, $message, $header, $attachments );
```

Now, the %title% should take the value of $header. In this case "test".

How can I realize that? I tried something with filters, but It did not work. :-(

Greets, yab86

Answer (score 0):

Means u need to add the header part in the mail.Same function i have used for that.
please tell your problem?

Comment: No, I need a new tag for the plugin wp better mail. I called the tag %title% and that tag should always take the value of the var $header.

Comment: You can use also Shortcode  i.e. function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );